# Telerik MVC grid related

Tags: asp.net-mvc, grid, telerik

Telerik grid used column template for error if error has val 0 then column color green otherwise different it is applying load of page whenever filter on error code column given template is disappears how can I achieve template also when filter applied also

Comment: Can you provide the code which you already tried ?

Comment: Telerik.grid().Column(bound=bound.errorcode.template(@text ---color code--).Filterable(true).Like this code is then click filter button in ui template is disappearing

Comment: This code I tried mr.manoj